# Why does Python's argparse module dynamically (and implicitly) create the variable name instead of forcing explicit assignment?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

Basically, for `argparse`, I'll do:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="This is a command line parser!")
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('--send-emails', action="store_true", help="This will send production emails")
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.send_emails:
  send_emails()
```

Where `"--send-emails"` is automatically cased to `"send_emails"`. This seems a bit conventiony/implicity. Forcing a `name=` parameter feels like it would be more explicit.

Are there any PEPs or mailing list threads that I can read to help me understand the rationale for this?

Edit: I found this PEP for argparse, but a quick skim seems to indicate it doesn't address this specific thing. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0389/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`optparse` does the same thing - derive the default `dest` from the option strings.

`getopt` also pairs the `option strings` or `long options` (i.e. the argument flags) with the values.

So `argparse` is copying its predecessors.

`argparse` differs in that it also parses `positional` arguments.  For those the `dest` is the first (non-keyword) parameter.

Overall `argparse` tries to give you as much power as possible, while making common cases relatively simple, mostly through the use of logical defaults.  `nargs`, `action`, `type`, `default` all have defaults.  Optional keyword parameters are widespread through out the public API.

Answer (score 0):

The rationale is that it is more convenient to only specify the name once.  You can provide an explicit name if you like, with the `dest="name"` argument.  But why say it twice?

Comment: Part of what was different here was there was a convention around the conversion  "show-items" might have gotten converted to "show_items", for example.